# Update the value of older rows with the most recent rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe with columns - id, date, region, some_numeric_fields

id and date identifies entire row uniquely like primary key. My dataframe is sorted by date in descending order.

What I want is to replace all the values of region with the value of region from the most recent date row matching id and same for the date field and keeping numeric fields intact.

Sample Input

[image]

Sample Output

[image]

The data is too large so I don't prefer to iterate through each and every row instead I want something faster.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) for replace all values without first to `NaN` by mask created by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) and then repalce `NaN` by `forward filling` by `ffill` ([`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with `method='ffill'`):

```
df[['date','region']] = df[['date','region']].mask(df['id'].duplicated()).ffill()
```

Another solution is use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) + [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
g = df.groupby('id')
df['region'] = g['region'].transform('first')
df['date'] =   g['date'].transform('first')
```

Last solution is aggregate [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), remove column `region` and and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) `s`:

```
s = df.groupby('id')['date','region'].first()
df = df.drop(['date','region'], axis=1).join(s, on='id')
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[123,123,221,221,221],
                   'date':pd.to_datetime(['2017/05/22','2017/05/21',
                                          '2017/05/11','2017/05/10','2017/05/09']),
                   'region':['region1','region2','region3','region4','region5'],
                   'num field':[1,2,3,4,5]})
print (df)
        date   id  num field   region
0 2017-05-22  123          1  region1
1 2017-05-21  123          2  region2
2 2017-05-11  221          3  region3
3 2017-05-10  221          4  region4
4 2017-05-09  221          5  region5


df[['date','region']] = df[['date','region']].mask(df['id'].duplicated()).ffill()
print (df)
        date   id  num field   region
0 2017-05-22  123          1  region1
1 2017-05-22  123          2  region1
2 2017-05-11  221          3  region3
3 2017-05-11  221          4  region3
4 2017-05-11  221          5  region3
```